# Ethics: How to deal with a professor who will not accept their inaccurarcy in judging my work?

Tags: ethics, professorship, research-undergraduate

First, I am a mathematics major who is doing an REU ([Research Experiences for Undergraduates](https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/)) in mathematics at my school. Initially, I wanted to do an REU outside of my school because I have had this professor before, and being in his class is difficult, but not unbearable. Right now, it is unbearable. For the first project, he has asked me to prove a proposition in category theory, and his criticism is not helpful nor is it actually advice. He has went as far as to say "this is your project, not mine", even though my proof is actually correct for the problem at hand; I have seen other verified proofs and had mine verified by mathematicians. It just makes me feel stupid, and I feel depressed and stressed coming to school everyday. What are my options in this situation and what is the most ethical?

Comment: Hard to judge this from a distance. It could be a personality issue, it could be a mathematical issue, and it could be that he just thinks you missed something important and need to think deeper.

Comment: It could be the first, but it is not the last two, since I am using the sources he suggested, and his suggestions are just confusing and are misunderstandings of the structures.

Comment: What do you mean by "his criticism is not helpful nor is it actually advice"? What is the criticism? What do you mean by "had mine verified by mathematicians"?

Comment: His advice is almost always "Nope. That is wrong." with no tips on how to improve, or just bad advice. For example, in the proof you rely on certain commutative diagrams. One of them he misunderstood since a canonical isomorphism does not mean the object is mapped to the object, it just means their paths commute so the objects are isomorphic(the associativity). But that turned into an ordeal that left me with panic because that's not what the diagram means. And for the verification means that other professors who are math specialists have reviewed the proof and says that it is acceptable.

Comment: Have you asked for clarification of what is wrong? Is it possible you are not communicating the concepts in your proofs correctly or leaving assumptions unstated?

Comment: Yes, of course. I always ask, "well what is the exact problem?" or if when he gives advice, I would say "I do not understand". And legitimately, the only thing he seems to do is force me to work on it by myself with his inaccurate advice and misunderstanding of the problem. I promise, I am doing the upmost to communicate and have my proof clear for those to read. I state my assumptions, what I am using (which are all valid), and why one thing follows from another.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be asking about 'ethics' rather than say 'etiquette'?

Comment: By professors who are math specialists, do you actually mean math professors? And whether you are correct is of course impossible for me to tell from this, but your description of a canonical isomorphism is not actually comprehensible to me in the current form.

Comment: @Anyon, my guess here is that the OP is asking about the ethics of the professor - or even making a claim of unethical behavior on his part.

Comment: @Buffy The last sentence would seem to contradict that interpretation.

Comment: @Anyon, right you are.

Comment: Please expand "REU".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your professor is not being "unethical".  It's possible he's a difficult person but ethics is not a part of this.

There's a pretty good chance that if your professor says your proof is not correct, that it really isn't.  And he may not be as unhelpful as you think.  Students sometimes think an instructor is unhelpful if they don't give them the answer any time they're stuck.  But simply giving you the answer won't make you a better mathematician.  Forcing you to keep plugging at it until you find the answer on your own *will* make you a better mathematician.

My advice:  Consider the possibility that he's right, you're not and that he wants you to keep working at it until you solve it on your own and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

It’s really hard to understand your question.  In your questions and comments you’re using language in imprecise and confusing ways.  I’d imagine that when you try to explain math you’re probably also explaining it in imprecise and confusing ways.  My best guess is your professor genuinely doesn’t understand what your argument is.  Have you tried writing it down carefully line-by-line and thinking through whether each step is totally clear and explained precisely?  It also might help to try to explain it to another student.